# In how many ways you can paint 14 rooms, if you have two types of paint: red and blue?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In how many ways you can paint 14 rooms, if you have two types of paint: red and blue? (Mixing the paint together is not allowed).

$2^{14} = 16384$ ways

I'm not sure if this correct because I started to think that I can paint each wall a different color which is different then $2^{14} = 16384$, because $2^{14}$ only tells me how many ways I can paint a 14 rooms either red or blue.

Comment: There is always a certain amount of interpretation needed in "word problems." If you want to be explicit, you can say that you are assuming only one colour can be used per room. Then $2^{14}$ is right.

Comment: If you can use different colors on different walls of the same room, what about different parts of the same wall? In actual rooms there are often baseboards or window frames or molding high up on the wall that can be (and often is) painted a different color.

Answer (score 1):

It is a interpretation problem, my advice is to go to the simplest.
Imagine the subject allow you to paint each wall with different color, the how many walls have the room ? some have 6 or more walls. It does not seems logic. If it is not precised assumed it is not asked.

The simplest is considering you can paint the rooms with only one color each.
That way, you have 2 choice for the first, times 2 choice for the second etc.
i.e. $$2\times2\times2...\times2=2^{14}$$

Have a nice day.